# disable TypeHints in the Document Generated for Spring Data ElasticSearch 4.X

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Is there a way i can disable TypeHints in the Document Generated for Spring Data ElasticSearch.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.mapping.meta-model.rules

I have the Mapping Definition for my elastic Index (7.X) Dynamic Mapping Set to Strict and when i am trying to Index a Document it was created a Field _class in the Elastic Document which is failing the Document Insertion into the ElasticSearch index 7.X with Below Error

```
Elasticsearch exception [type=strict_dynamic_mapping_exception, reason=mapping set to strict, dynamic introduction of [_class] within [_doc] is not allowed]
```

Comment: Hi actually I have found a workaround for this problem please check out it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66062703/is-there-any-way-to-force-spring-not-to-use-create-class-field-in-the-mapping/66118240#66118240 Not sure if it fits your case but in my it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this is not possible. You can create an [issue in Jira](https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATAES/issues) to have this implemented as a new feature, but beware that if type hints are not written, you wont be able to properly read collection-like values of generics.

For example if you have two classes `Foo` and `Bar` and in an entity you have a property of type `List<Object>` which contains `Foo`s and `Bar`s you won't be able to read back such an entity from Elasticsearch, because the type information of the objects would be lost.

Comment: For those who are intrested https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-881