# Is there any way to force spring not to use/create '_class' field in the mapping?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

The thing is on production servers we got mapping for Elasticsearch with dynamic set to strict. Currently, we use a rest level client to communicate with Elastisearch, however, we would like to migrate to spring-data-elasticsearch.
Unfortunately, it seems spring data force to use either _class or @TypeAlias which also interfere with the mapping itself. Is any way to use spring-data without _class or @TypeAlias?

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not possible. There is [an open issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/1454) for that.

**Edit 25.04.2021:**

this feature will be available from the next version (4.3) on.

Comment: Ah, what bad news. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found a workaround for it.

**Be aware of using it when your elasticsearch model uses inheritance**.

To solve this problem create class like this:

```
public class CustomMappingEsConverter extends MappingElasticsearchConverter {

public CustomMappingEsConverter(MappingContext<? extends ElasticsearchPersistentEntity<?>, ElasticsearchPersistentProperty> mappingContext, GenericConversionService conversionService) {
    super(mappingContext, conversionService);
}

@Override
public Document mapObject(@Nullable Object source) {
    Document target = Document.create();
    if (source != null) {
        this.write(source, target);
    }
    target.remove("_class"); // << workaround to remove those _class field in elasticsearch
    return target;
    }
}
```

And register the bean:

```
@Configuration
public class MappingEsConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public CustomMappingEsConverter CustomMappingElasticsearchConverter(MappingContext<? extends ElasticsearchPersistentEntity<?>, ElasticsearchPersistentProperty> mappingContext,
                                                                        GenericConversionService genericConversionService) {
        return new CustomMappingEsConverter(mappingContext, genericConversionService);
    }
}
```

After this changes I was able to use spring data without additional field _class.